# How to set Alias Interceptor's parameter with annotations

Tags: java, struts2, annotations, interceptor, struts2-convention-plugin

I'm a newbie in Struts 2

I want to use Alias Interceptor with annotations.

```java
@Action(value="profile", results={
  @Result(name=SUCCESS, location="/home.jsp")}, interceptorRefs={
      @InterceptorRef(value="alias", params={"aliases", "#{'username':'name'}"}),
      @InterceptorRef(value="basicStack")})
```

But I get always the error:

> WARNING: Caught OgnlException while setting property 'aliases' on type 'com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [Alias Interceptor documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/alias-interceptor.html), the only accepted parameter is `aliasesKey`, used to change the name of the **Action property** containing your aliases Map (the default is `aliases`, and generally you don't need to change it).

You simply need to apply your aliases as Action parameter, instead of Interceptor parameter:

```
    @Action(value = "profile", 
           params = { "aliases", "#{'username':'name'}"},
          results = { @Result(name=SUCCESS, location="/home.jsp")}, 
  interceptorRefs = { @InterceptorRef(value="alias"),
                      @InterceptorRef(value="basicStack")})
```